# Behaviour of a c++ model update from a different thread from which the QML QtQuick2 engine is running

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtquick2

The scenario has following components:

- C++ QAbstractItemModel derived model class created in main thread
- QML QtQuick2 Engine instantiated in main thread
- Worker boost::thread spawned from main thread upon user interaction

The relations between these components:

- The C++ model is exposed through a Q_PROPERTY of a type registered with qmlRegisterSingletonType<>() to the QML Engine.
- The worker thread updates the model through a method that invokes "emit data_changed(...)"

The question: in which thread does the callback of the "emit data_changed(...)" happen?

**Note**

A key element in this question is that the started thread is not qt aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the worker thread invokes a signal method on some `QObject`. This is perfectly thread-safe, and a valid thing to do. The signal's implementation compares the current thread to the thread of every slot, and determines what kind of connection to use (if the connection is of automatic type).

As long as you connect to said signal using automatic or queued connections, the slots will get invoked in the `thread()` of their `QObject` instance.

It doesn't matter what thread the signal is invoked in, and it doesn't matter whether that thread is a Qt thread or not.

If you provide a context object to a connection to a functor, the functor will execute in the thread of the context object, so you can do thread-safe functor invocations on objects that way :)

For example:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <thread>

class Object : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void ping();
  Q_SLOT void pong() { 
    qDebug() << "hello on thread" << QThread::currentThread();
    qApp.quit();
  });
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  Object obj;
  qDebug() << "main thread is" << QThread::currentThread();
  QObject::connect(&obj, &Object::ping, &obj, &Object:pong);
  QObject::connect(&obj, &Object::ping, []{
    qDebug() << "context-free functor invoked on thread" << QThread::currentThread();
  });
  QObject::connect(&obj, &QObject::ping, &obj, []{
    qDebug() << "context-ful functor invoked on thread" << QThread::currentThread();
  });
  auto thread = std::thread([&obj]{
    emit obj.ping();
  });
  int rc = app.exec();
  thread.join();
  return rc;
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! The key is boiling it down to a QObject created in the main thread and emitting its signal from another thread.

The only thing I can't be a 100% (as in without a doubt) is that the connection type for signals and slots between the cpp model and the QML engine are of the automatic type or the queued type. Nonetheless this seems to be a reasonable assumption.

Also Your example was very useful but it did not compile for me. [Here](https://gist.github.com/psimona/ecefd220cf0d40e31b9d) is a revised version. Feel free to edit your post to include it if you want.

Comment: @ramses728 Add the `#include "main.moc"` line at the end :) Then re-run qmake and build again.

Comment: That worked still you have some syntax errors updated the [git gist](https://gist.github.com/psimona/ecefd220cf0d40e31b9d)